# Adding parameters to only external links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add a parameter to only external links (links redirecting to external websites).
This is what I did so far:

```js
      <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        jQuery('document').ready(function(){
          jQuery( 'a' ).each( function( index, element ){
            var url = jQuery( element ).prop( 'href' );
            
            if (url.host !== window.location.host){
              if ( url.indexOf( '?' ) == -1 ) {
                url += '?ref=xxx';
              } else {
                url += '&ref=xxx';
              }

              jQuery( element ).prop( 'href', url );
            }
          } );
        });
      </script>
```

However, this will add `ref=xxx` to all links (internal and external). Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` does not contain a `.host` property; the `href` `.prop()` returns a string.

To access the host name, you'll want to convert each of your URLs to a URL with [`new URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL).

Note that you'll also have to update the `.indexOf()` to point to `url.host.indexOf()` as well.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  jQuery('a').each(function(index, element) {
    var url = new URL(jQuery(element).prop('href'));

    if (url.host !== window.location.host) {
      if (url.host.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        url += '?ref=xxx';
      } else {
        url += '&ref=xxx';
      }

      jQuery(element).prop('href', url);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/test.html">Internal</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">External</a>
```